# Replace carriage returns in list python

Tags: python, list, csv, carriage-return

I have a list of values and need to remove errant carriage returns whenever they occur in a list of values.

the format of the file that I am looking to remove these in is as follows.

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|val
ue 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|va
lue 4|value 5
```

I am looking to address a situation like the one above where there are errant carriage returns in the 3rd and 4th values for the last 2 rows of data.

I have seen a few posts for how to address this but so far nothing has worked for this situation.  I have pasted the code I have attempted so far.

```
import os
import sys

filetoread = 'C:\temp\test.dat'
filetowrite = 'C:\emp\test_updated.dat'

'''
Attempt 1
'''
with open(filetoread, "r+b") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "w") as fixed:
        for line in inf:
            fixed.write(line)


'''
Attempt 2
'''           
for line in filetoread:
    line = line.replace("\n", "")


'''
Attempt 3
'''
with open(filetoread, "r") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if "\n" in line:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: You are either not handling newlines, or handling *all* newlines. Is the number of `|` separators constant on each line? Then you can detect when the newline needs to be removed.

Comment: And just to check, your CSV file is not using quotes around those values, right? Because the `csv` module can *handle newlines in quoted values*.

Comment: One reason your code may not be working is the paths you're using. Python reads single \ characters as escapes, and `\t` is the tab character. So, `'C:\temp\test.dat'` is being interpreted as `'C:<tab>emp<tab>est.dat'`. To fix this, use a raw string literal - put `r` just before the first quote: `r'C:\temp\test.dat'`.

Comment: The number of | separators is constant (31).  IE the list has 32 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count the number of fields, to match 5 per line:

```
import re
with open(filetoread, "r+b") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "w") as fixed:
        for l in re.finditer('(?:.*?\|){4}(?:.*?)\n', inf.read(), re.DOTALL):
            fixed.write(l.group(0).replace('\n','') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The \n character is a line feed. \r is the carriage return:

http://www.asciitable.com/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

So,

```
> line.replace("\n", "")
```

should be

```
 line.replace("\r", "")
```

Do check if it's really \r alone, or the \r\n pair. Windows/DOS uses \r\n,
Mac & Co uses \r, Linux uses \n alone

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I'm assuming you have extra newlines (`'\n'`) not carriage returns (`'\r'`).

```
def remove_newlines_in_fields(data, ncols, sep):
    sep_count = 0
    for c in data:
        if c == sep:
            sep_count += 1
        if c == '\n':
            if sep_count == ncols - 1:
                yield c
                sep_count = 0
        else:
            yield c
```

Also note that if you have newlines in your rightmost column this won't work properly.  (The partial column will be prepended to the next row.)

Here it is in action:

```
>>> s = '''field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
... value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
... value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
... value 1|value 2|val
... ue 3|value 4|value 5
... value 1|value 2|value 3|va
... lue 4|value 5'''
>>> print(''.join(remove_newlines_in_fields(s, 5, '|')))
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
value 1|value 2|value 3|value 4|value 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove any carriage return characters embedded in each field:

```
with open(filetoread, "rb") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "w") as fixed:
        for line in (line.rstrip() for line in inf):
            fields = (field.replace('\r', '') for field in line.split('|'))
            fixed.write('|'.join(fields) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

**if the line you read from a text file is empty with ^M at the end, in only *that* case, python will read as two empty lines:

infile:**
Cookie: login=admin; session=oNvChuTLIyFhParkQ0c4UswT^M
^M
{"order":["descending","time"],"where":{"access_logs":{"time":{"<=":1675900799,">=":1673308800}},"users":{},"groups":{},"time_zones":{}},"object":"access_logs","fields":["COUNT(*)"],"join":"LEFT"}

output of: for line in infile:print('LINE:'+line+'!')

**LINE:Cookie: login=admin; session=oNvChuTLIyFhParkQ0c4UswT!

LINE:!

LINE:!

LINE:!

LINE:{"order":["descending","time"],"where":{"access_logs":{"time":{"<=":1675900799,">=":1673308800}},"users":{},"groups":{},"time_zones":{}},"object":"access_logs","fields":["COUNT(*)"],"join":"LEFT"}!**

Comment: It is very hard to read and understand your answer. Please edit it and format using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).